# convert a timestamp to UTC (or GMT) time?

Tags: javascript, mysql

I retrieved a datetime value from a mysql datebase (a 'datetime' column value), and after retrieving it via an ajax call, when I created the Date object, it considered the datetime to be in EST time.  But in the DB its stored in GMT time.  How can I get javascript to consider the value as GMT time?

Here's my code:

```
timestamp = new Date(data[i].startTime);
alert(timestamp.getTime());
```

The alert shows the same exact time, but considers it in local time (EST).  IE:  If data[i].startTime reads as `"2012-11-27 09:05:18"`, then the alert reports `1354025118.`  This number of milliseconds though refers to `2012-11-27 09:05:18 GMT-0500` (or `2012-11-27 14:05:18`)

Comment: How about using `CONVERT_TZ` on the MySQL side?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get javascript to consider the value as GMT time?

To make the [`Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) not use the local (current user) timezone, use a datetime string with timezone information, e.g. `"2012-11-27 09:05:18 GMT"`. However, it is hard to find a format that is reliable parsed by every browser - the [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) algorithms are implementation-dependent. Better, use a unix timestamp, i.e. milliseconds since [unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), or use a regulare expression to break the string down in its parts and then feed those into [`Date.UTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC).

Comment: timestamp = new Date(data[i].startTime + " GMT");

Comment: Have you tested this across all browsers?

Comment: No, only under Chrome.  The web application I am making is internal, and we only use Chrome with it.